# getting data in console but not in my html view in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-forms, angular4-router, angular4-httpclient

I am searching data by name which is working fine, then trying to get the details of searched product (accessing single product detail from the product array). The data is getting displayed in console but not in my HTML view.
Here my component code goes

```
export class SearchdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: Product;

    ngOnInit() {
          this.getComponent();
       }
    goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
 private componentUrl = 'HereMyRestServicePostUrlGoes';
  constructor(private http:Http, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location) {
     }

   getComponent(): Observable<Product[]> {
    const name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
    let obj = { name: name }
       let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
         var config = {
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                };
      headers = headers.append('Content-Type' : 'application/json');
      const url = `${this.componentUrl}`;
      return this.http.post<Product[]>(url, body, config).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(product => { 
            this.product = product; 
            console.log(this.Product);
              );
            }
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="wide">
</div>
<div class="hero-bkg-animated">
<h2>Product Details</h2>
<form class="form-style-9">
<div >

  <div>
<div class="table-responsive">    
<table *ngIf="product" class="table table-striped">
  <tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td>{{product.name}}</td></tr>
   <tr><td><b>Address</b></td><td>{{product.address}}</td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Router code:

```
 { path: 'detail/:name', component: SearchdetailComponent }
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc2JV.png)

Comment: looking your code product is a observable. try {{(product | async)?.name}}

Comment: getting this error : InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*ngIf="product"
```

This doesnt mean anything unless `product` is a boolean.

You need to use if condition on property like this

```
<div >
    <table *ngFor="let p of product" class="table table-striped">
      <tr *ngIf="p.name.length>0"><td><b>Name</b></td><td>{{p.name}}</td></tr>
       <tr *ngIf="p.address.length>0"><td><b>Address</b></td><td>{{p.address}}</td></tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: I am sharing data among the component by using  @Input() product: Product; i am new to angular so not sure.

Comment: No problem with using Product as Input(), Just that in html you have to check if on one of the properties of Product, You can check directly on Product. Try above code and let me know if you face issues

Comment: getting this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object.eval

Comment: You have 2 variables named product.!! One is with Input() and other is with type of Observable. Fix that.

Comment: Fixed, still data is showing in console but not in view.

Comment: You dont need product: Observable<Product[]>; Instead you can use simply product: Product[]; and since this is an array you need to traverse through each object using *NgFor Check updated answer

Comment: I am getting the data on search like this means the whole array, but  i want to get the details of individual product by name. I am getting all the product on search but i want to get the details of specific element on click of that element.

Comment: Thats why there is *NgFor.

Comment: Correct Dheeraj, but i am trying to get data of individual product on click. That is details of individual element.

Comment: well then you have to pass a product variable which is not an array.

Comment: Thats what i have done in above code. Data is showing properly in console but not in view. :-(

Comment: did you update variable name as product was declared twice.? If yes please update your question with modified code. in update section.